# equivalent command for azure x gcloud

Tags: docker, azure-functions, azure-aks

I was wondering what the equivalent command for azure would be:

```
 cloud auth configure-docker
```

I'm trying to use a "docker push" inside azure kubernetes but I can't because it asks for authentication.

Comment: docker push to acr?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the [`az acr login`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/acr?view=azure-cli-latest#az-acr-login) command should be the equivalent to that. There are [different ways to authenticate as documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-authentication).

You will likely want to go the [service principal route](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-authentication#service-principal) but if you using [AAD Pod Identity](https://github.com/Azure/aad-pod-identity), then I believe you could go the managed identity route which is usually better since service principals have a one year expiry for their passwords.